# What do the columns in Modern 'yarn upgrade-interactive' mean?

Tags: yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

What is the meaning of the column labels displayed by Yarn Modern's `yarn upgrade-interactive`?

As near as I can tell

- "current" means the currently specified range in `package.json`,
- "range" sometimes means the currently available package that matches the specification, but sometimes not, and
- "latest" is the latest available version.

In other words, the names don't seem to match the meaning very clearly and make it easy to install a package version that's not specified. For example while "range" often shows a new version that meets spec, it can also sometimes who one that does not. E.g., I have

```
? Pick the packages you want to upgrade.          Current          Range            Latest

 > @react-native-picker/picker ----------------- ◉ 2.4.2 -------- ◯ 2.4.4 --------
```

which could easily result in my installing an out of range version (despite the title "range" and the green highlighting.

All of this is *much* more confusing and error prone than the Classic version (not to mention no breakdown into sections (development, peer, etc.).

What am I missing? Has the purpose of `upgrade-interactive` change, or is there a specific way to interpret columns that I'm not grasping?